# Transform a .txt file into a Matlab timeseries object

Tags: matlab, time-series

i have a .txt file of the following form:

time1; value1
time2; value2
...

Is there a simple simple way to transform this txt file into a timeseriesobject? timeseries(data,time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [dlmread](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)

```
ts=dlmread('name.txt', ';');
```

Should read in your data as a matrix. If you really want it as a timeseries then use

`timeseries(ts(:, 2), ts(:, 1)`

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be to use MATLAB's [csvread](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) function.

```
filename = 'csvlist.txt';
M = csvread(filename)
```

or

```
 M = dlmread(filename,';')
```

Comment: If I do this, i will gett an 
Error using dlmread |
Mismatch betwenn file and format string. |
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 1, field number 2) ==> ; 79\n

Comment: take a look at nivag's answer.